# Date format conversions using ruby

Tags: ruby

How to change the date format from MM/DD/YEAR to YEAR-MM-DD using ruby?
Data is read from file.

Beacuse the standard date format of rally is like 2013-10-20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `YYYY-MM-DD` is the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation for dates. So for that format you can most simply:

```
require 'date'
puts Date.strptime( '10/20/2013', '%m/%d/%Y' ).iso8601
Date.strptime( '10/20/2013', '%m/%d/%Y' ).to_s
```

More generically, you can specify the formatting string via `strftime`:

```
require 'date'
def convert_date( date_str, in_format='%m/%d/%Y', out_format='%Y-%m-%d' )
  Date.strptime(date_str,in_format).strftime(out_format)
end

puts convert_date('10/20/2013')
#=> 2013-10-20
```

Here are the format options for [date formatting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime):

- **`%Y`** Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least) `-0001`, `0000`, `1995`, `2009`, `14292`, etc.

  - `%-Y` not padded (`1`..`2013` and on)
- **`%C`** year / 100 (round down, e.g. `20` in 2009)
- **`%y`** year % 100 (`00`..`99`)

- **`%m`** Month of the year, zero-padded (`01`..`12`)

  - `%-m` not-padded (`1`..`12`)
  - `%_m` blank-padded ( `1`..`12`)
- **`%B`** The full month name (`January`)

  - `%^B`  uppercased (`JANUARY`)
- **`%b`** The abbreviated month name (`Jan`)

  - `%^b`  uppercased (`JAN`)
- **`%h`** Equivalent to `%b`

- **`%d`** Day of the month, zero-padded (`01`..`31`)

  - `%-d`  not-padded (`1`..`31`)
  - `%_d`  blank-padded ( `1`..`31`)
  - `%e`   blank-padded (same as `%_d`)
- **`%j`** Day of the year (`001`..`366`)

- **`%A`** The full weekday name (`Sunday`)

  - `%^A` uppercased (`SUNDAY`)
- **`%a`** The abbreviated name (`Sun`)

  - `%^a`  uppercased (`SUN`)
- **`%u`** Day of the week (Monday is 1, `1`..`7`)
- **`%w`** Day of the week (Sunday is 0, `0`..`6`)

- **`%U`** Week number of the year. The week starts with Sunday.  (`00`..`53`)
- **`%W`** Week number of the year. The week starts with Monday.  (`00`..`53`)

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'Date'
p Date.strptime('10/20/2013','%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #=> "2013-10-20"
```

Or if you do not want to use the Date module:

```
my_string = '10/20/2013'
p  my_string.split('/').rotate(2).join('-') #=> "2013-10-20"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime) to parse the date. After that you can print the date using the members day, month and year of the DateTime object.

```
d = DateTime.strptime('28/10/2013', '%m/%d/%Y')
puts "{d.year}-#{d.month}-#{d.day}"
```

EDIT: actually a better option for the print is to use [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) as suggested by hirolau.